# mod_wsgi DaemonProcess mode gets problem with httpd graceful reload

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using `httpd -k graceful` to dynamically reload my server, and I use time.sleep in python code to make a slow request, and I expected the active requests would't be interrupted after apache reload. But it did.

So I tried a simple python server using CGI, it works well. Then I tried mod_wsgi using apache process (only specifying `WSGIScriptAlias`), and it works well, too.

So I found that the problem is the `WSGIDaemonProcess`, which I originally used.

Then in the mod_wsgi doc I found this:

> eviction-timeout=sss
>
> When a daemon process is sent the graceful restart signal, usually SIGUSR1, to restart a process, this timeout controls how many seconds the process will wait, while still accepting new requests, before it reaches an idle state with no active requests and shutdown.
>
> If this timeout is not specified, then the value of the graceful-timeout will instead be used. If the graceful-timeout is not specified, then the restart when sent the graceful restart signal will instead happen immediately, with the process being forcibly killed, if necessary, when the shutdown timeout has expired.

when I thought I'm going to find the reason, I found that these arguments(and i tried `graceful-timeout` too) didn't work at all.The requests were still interrupted by graceful reload. So why?

I'm using `apache 2.4.6`, with mpm mode `prefork`.  And `modwsgi 4.6.5`, I compiled it myself and replaced my old-version mod_wsgi.so with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from GrahamDumpleton@Github: (https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/383)

What you are seeing is exactly as expected. Apache does not pass graceful restart signals onto managed sub processes, it only passes them onto its own child worker processes. For managed processes it will send a `SIGTERM` and it will brutally kill them after 3 or 5 seconds (can't remember exactly how long) if they haven't shutdown. There is no way around it. It is a limitation of Apache.

The eviction timeout thus only applies as the docs say to when a 'daemon process' is sent a graceful restart signal directly. That is, restarting Apache as a whole gracefully doesn't do anything, but send the graceful restart signal to the pid of the daemon processes themselves will.

So the only solution if this behaviour is important is to ensure you use `display-name` option to `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive so daemon processes named uniquely compared to Apache processes, and then send signals to them direct only.

Usually this only becomes an issue because some Linux systems completely ignore the fact that Apache has a perfectly good log file rotation system and instead do external log file rotation by renaming log files once a day and then attempting a graceful restart. People will see issues with interrupted requests they don't expect. In this case you should use Apache's own log file rotation mechanism if it is important and not rely on external log file rotation systems.